# How to create multiple stages in serverless framwork

Tags: serverless-framework

i'm trying yo create multiple stages in serverless with no success.

Here is my `serverless.yml`:

```
service: some-cache-updater
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: dev

functions:
  scheduledUpdater:
    handler: handler.scheduledUpdater
    timeout: 120
```

What i wish to add is a *prod* stage with a different timeout.

Can i do it in the same yml?

Any way an example or a reference will be helpful... thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use Serverless' `$self` reference interpolation which can include further interpolation.

Define a custom variable where necessary. You can also use a default value if the variable doesn't exist.

Example:

```
service: some-cache-updater

custom:
  functimeout:
    prod: 120
    uat: 60

provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs8.10
    stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}

functions: 
    scheduledUpdater:
    handler: handler.scheduledUpdater
    # Lookup stage key from custom.functimeout. If it doesn't exist
    # default to 10
    timeout: ${self:custom.functimeout.${self:provider.stage}, '10'}
```

Then, when you deploy you can pass the `--stage prod` or `--stage uat` argument. In this example, no setting the stage will default to `dev`

Answer (score 7):

serverless.yml:

```
...
provider:
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
...
```

Command line:

```
sls deploy --stage prod
```

**${opt:stage, 'dev'}** takes the value passed from command line **--stage** option. In this case **prod**. If no option is passed **dev** is taken as default.

More info here:
https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#recursively-reference-properties