# Deploy the same function to different endpoint on ASW Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a function which I successfully deploy to AWS Lambda using the **Serverless framework**.

This function relies on some environment variables which I set in the `serverless.yml` file like this

```
    provider:
        name: aws
        runtime: nodejs8.10
        stage: ${opt:stage,'dev'}
        region: ${opt:region,'eu-west-1'}
        deploymentBucket:
            name: my-bucket
        environment:
            MY_ENV_VAR: 'the value of my var'

functions:
    myFunction:
        handler: handler.myHandler
        events:
            - http:
                  path: executeFunction
                  method: post
```

Now I want to deploy the same logic, just with a different value of `MY_ENV_VAR` **to a different endpoint**. If I change simply the value of `MY_ENV_VAR` and then deploy, the endpoint does not change. But even if I change the `deploymentBucket` and the name of the function, i.e. `myFunction`, the deployment generates always the same endpoint.

Is it possible to deploy the same function to a different endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the service name is not a very scalable solution. You should retain the same service name and deploy using a different --stage to get a different endpoint depending on the stage it's deployed to. You can use the stage to manage environment variables so that it can be set to one value on one stage and another value on another stage. See an example in [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895367/how-to-create-multiple-stages-in-serverless-framwork). Also, nodejs8.10 is EOL on AWS. Use nodejs10.x instead.

Comment: I thought --stage was meant for segregation of dev, qa, prod environments. I read your suggestion as a possibility to use --stage also as a way to differentiate installations for different clients or configurations. Can you confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a while I figure out the solution.

The first parameter of the serverless.yml file is `service: myService`.

Changing that parameter actually generates a deployment which creates different endpoint.