# Serverless single stack with multiple stages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless, serverless-framework

Using the serverless framework it is possible to specify a CloudFormation stack using the stackName variable (as described [here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml#general-settings)).
When working with different stages using the CLI parameters and serverless.yml code similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895367/how-to-create-multiple-stages-in-serverless-framwork#answer-57144934) all other stages and corresponding resources are deleted from the specified stack when deploying e.g. they are overwritten with the new stages lambda/polcies/etc.
I want both `serverless deploy` and `serverless deploy --stage prod` be deployed to the same stack and create different versions of the resources.

Is there an easy way to have multiple stages under a single stack? Or is this maybe a bad idea from the get-go?

My serverless.yml looks similar to this atm:

```yaml
service: serviceName
frameworkVersion: "3"

provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs18.x
    stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
    stackName: stackName
    region: eu-central-1
    deploymentBucket:
        name: sl-deployment-bucket
    httpApi:
        shouldStartNameWithService: true
        [...]

functions:
    lambdaName:
        name: lambdaName-${sls:stage}
        handler: handler.handle
        events:
            - httpApi:
                  method: get
                  path: /get-stuff
                  [...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend against trying to do that as Serverless Framework internals are operating under the assumption that each stage is deployed as a separate CloudFormation stack. Each package/deployment will generate a stage-specific CloudFormation template that will then be deployed, which means that each deploy will remove everything else (unless defined under `resources` explicitly), which you already experienced when trying to manually set the `stackName`.

Is there any particular reason why you'd like to keep all stages in a single CloudFormation stack?

Comment: There is no specific need for having it in one stack. We talked about it in my team and the question just came if we could do it like that for "aesthetic" purposes. Meaning if you go into one stack you can really see everything related to that specific functionality.

I think I will just have different stacks, since it doesn't seem to be possible easily/useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have have to include the environment name in the `stackName` property in the `provider` block.

Comment: What do you mean with "environment name"?

I want to use the same stack for both `serverless deploy` and `serverless deploy --stage prod` that's why I am specifying a stack using stackName.

Comment: Means - `stackName: ${sls:stage}-stackName` and `name: lambdaName`. However, you should be fine omitting `name: lambdaName`

Comment: Yes, but I don't like the name it gives the lambdas automatically for some stacks. Something like: "stackName-stage-handler" - for some of my lambdas this is redundant (similar stackName and handler name). Thank you for pointing it out again :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).